# Multiple Instance with different service packs in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, instance

I would like to install a Default instance with SQL Server 2008 R2 RTM and I want to install another named instance with SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2. Is this possible?

Comment: beside this I have a database size of 300GB,Need to make sure  to change to sp2 from rtm and data need to be exact!

Comment: Service pack only deals with the components and not with any type of data in DB.

Comment: And why would you like to keep your SQL Server without SP in totally unsupported way. Is this for testing. Answer is of course it is possible

Comment: I want to upgrade my SQl server to sp2,How can I do without disturbing 300 GB of data(need to restore 300 gb data in sp2

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can choose instance to apply service pack.
Instance components along with shared components between side by side instances will be upgraded to higher service pack.

Sql server has two types of component\features.
1. Instance specific features
2. Shared Features

When you upgrade one component with a given instance name to a new version or service pack, you must upgrade all components of that instance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but you have to understand that there are certain shared components. See [Work with Multiple Versions and Instances of SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143694.aspx).